# How to position a common label for multiple plots using gtable in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been attempting to solve this issue for a considerable amount of time with no success. I am creating multiple partial dependence plots (PDPs) and utilising a package called `zenplots` to lay them out. However, the issue I am having is I cannot figure out a way to have a common legend for the multiple plots. I have tried placing them on a grid and plotting and tried changing the positioning of the grobs... but I cant figure it out. For example:
[image: example of layout]

In the above plot, all PDPs are on the same scale and I would like a single legend. Currently, when I produce the image, it plots a legend for each individual plot. Whereas, what I want is something like the image below (which I made in photoshop):
[image: plot with 1 legend]

The code Im providing to produce the plots is somewhat long ( which I hope won't deter people)... but essentially it's only the `ggplot` part of the code that I need to manipulate. That is, Im creating the actual ggplot on lines 103-105 and more generally between lines 103-125, where I use `ggtable` to build the plots. For example, changing the `color` argument on line 115 to:  `guides(fill = FALSE,  color = "colour bar")` will create the legend for each plot... setting `color = FALSE` will remove the legends.

below is the code used to make the plots and it's application on the air quality data:

```
library(randomForest)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

pdpLayout <- function(data,
                   fit,
                   response,
                   pal = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu")),
                   gridSize = 10,
                   nmax = 500,
                   class = 1,
                   rug = TRUE,
                   ...) {
 
  
  data <- na.omit(data)
  
  
  # if (is.numeric(nmax) && nmax < nrow(data)) {
  #   data <- data[sample(nrow(data), nmax), , drop = FALSE]
  # }
  
  gridSize <- min(gridSize, nmax)
  predData <- predict(fit, data)
  
  vars <- names(data)
  vars <- vars[-match(response, vars)]
  datap <- data[,vars]
  

  zpath <- 1:length(vars)
  zdata <- datap
  zpairs <- t(sapply(1:(length(zpath)-1), function(i){
    z <- zpath[i:(i+1)]
    if (i %% 2 == 0) rev(z) else z
    }))
  zpairs <- cbind(vars[zpairs[, 1]], vars[zpairs[, 2]])
  
  
  # loop through vars and create a list of pdps for each pair
  pdplist <- vector("list", nrow(zpairs))
  
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(zpairs)) {
    ind <- zpairs[i, ]
    if (!is.na(ind[1])) {
      px <- pdp_data(data, ind, gridsize = gridSize)
      px$.pid <- i
      pdplist[[i]] <- px
    } else {
      pdplist[[i]] <- NULL
    }
  }
  
  pdplist <- bind_rows(pdplist)
  pdplist$fit <- predict(fit, pdplist)
  pdplist <- split(pdplist, pdplist$.pid)
  
  pdplist0 <- vector("list", nrow(zpairs))
  
  j <- 1
  for (i in 1:nrow(zpairs)) {
    ind <- zpairs[i, ]
    if (!is.na(ind[1])) {
      pdplist0[[i]] <- pdplist[[j]] %>%
        group_by(.data[[ind[1]]], .data[[ind[2]]]) %>%
        summarise(fit = mean(fit))
      j <- j + 1
    } else {
      pdplist0[[i]] <- NULL
    }
  }
  
  pdplist <- pdplist0
  pdplist0 <- NULL
  names(pdplist) <- paste(zpairs[, 2], zpairs[, 1], sep = "pp")
  message("Finished ice/pdp")
  
  # Set limits for pairs
  
    pdplist0 <- pdplist[!sapply(pdplist, is.null)]
    r <- range(sapply(pdplist0, function(x) range(x$fit)))
    limits <- range(labeling::rpretty(r[1], r[2]))
  
  
  # Zenplot graphing function
  data$pred <- predData
  z2index <- 0
  pdpnn <- function(zargs) {
    z2index <<- z2index + 1
    vars <- zpairs[z2index, ]
    pdp <- pdplist[[z2index]]
    if (!is.null(pdp)) {
      if (is.factor(pdp[[vars[1]]]) + is.factor(pdp[[vars[2]]]) == 1) {
        if (is.factor(pdp[[vars[1]]])) vars <- rev(vars)
        
        p <- ggplot(data = pdp, aes(x = .data[[vars[1]]], y = fit, color = .data[[vars[2]]])) +
          geom_line() +
          geom_rug(data = data, sides = "b", aes(y = .data[["pred"]]))
      } else {
        if (is.factor(pdp[[vars[1]]])) posx <- "jitter" else posx <- "identity"
        if (is.factor(pdp[[vars[2]]])) posy <- "jitter" else posy <- "identity"
        p <- ggplot(data = pdp, aes(x = .data[[vars[1]]], y = .data[[vars[2]]])) +
          geom_tile(aes(fill = fit)) +
          scale_fill_gradientn(name = "y-hat", colors = pal, limits = limits, oob = scales::squish)
        if (rug) {
          p <- p +
            geom_rug(data = data, sides = "b", position = posx, aes(color = .data[["pred"]])) +
            geom_rug(data = data, sides = "l", position = posy, aes(color = .data[["pred"]])) +
            scale_color_gradientn(name = "y-hat", colors = pal, limits = limits, oob = scales::squish)
        }
      }
      
      p <- p +
        guides(fill = FALSE,  color = FALSE) +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = "gray", fill = NA, size = 1.5)
        )
      
      
    } else {
      p <- ggplot() +
        theme(panel.background = element_blank())
    }
    
    ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
  }
  
  suppressMessages({
    zenplots::zenplot(zdata,
                      pkg = "grid", labs = list(group = NULL),
                      plot2d = pdpnn, ...
    )
  })
}




pdp_data <- function(d, var, gridsize = 30) {
  if (length(var) == 1) {
    pdpvar <- d[[var]]
    if (is.factor(pdpvar)) {
      gridvals <- levels(pdpvar)
    } else {
      gridvals <- seq(min(pdpvar, na.rm = T), max(pdpvar, na.rm = T), length.out = gridsize)
    }
    dnew <- do.call(rbind, lapply(gridvals, function(i) {
      d1 <- d
      d1[[var]] <- i
      d1
    }))
    if (is.factor(pdpvar)) dnew[[var]] <- factor(dnew[[var]], levels = levels(pdpvar), ordered = is.ordered(pdpvar))
  }
  else {
    pdpvar1 <- d[[var[1]]]
    pdpvar2 <- d[[var[2]]]
    
    if (is.factor(pdpvar1)) {
      gridvals1 <- levels(pdpvar1)
    } else {
      gridvals1 <- seq(min(pdpvar1, na.rm = T), max(pdpvar1, na.rm = T), length.out = gridsize)
    }
    if (is.factor(pdpvar2)) {
      gridvals2 <- levels(pdpvar2)
    } else {
      gridvals2 <- seq(min(pdpvar2, na.rm = T), max(pdpvar2, na.rm = T), length.out = gridsize)
    }
    gridvals <- expand.grid(gridvals1, gridvals2)
    
    
    dnew <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(gridvals), function(i) {
      d1 <- d
      d1[[var[1]]] <- gridvals[i, 1]
      d1[[var[2]]] <- gridvals[i, 2]
      d1
    }))
    if (is.factor(pdpvar1)) dnew[[var[1]]] <- factor(dnew[[var[1]]], levels = levels(pdpvar1), ordered = is.ordered(pdpvar1))
    if (is.factor(pdpvar2)) dnew[[var[2]]] <- factor(dnew[[var[2]]], levels = levels(pdpvar2), ordered = is.ordered(pdpvar2))
  }
  dnew$.id <- 1:nrow(d)
  rownames(dnew) <- NULL
  dnew
}
```

Now use some data to create the plots:

```
aq <- na.omit(airquality)
rf <- randomForest(Ozone~., data = aq)
pdpLayout(aq, rf, "Ozone")
```

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're not attached to zenplots, you might find the [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#controlling-guides-1) package useful, especially with regards to collecting guides.

Comment: I need zenplots. I know it's a niche problem. I have found a far from ideal solution that technically answers my above question. I have found a way to display just one legend. However, finding a consistent position for the legend is proving tricky. I think I will have to ask a separate question